# Change ownership of shared memory

Tags: shared-memory, ownership

When I run `ipcs -m`, I can see a list of the shared memory segments on the system, like

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x00000000 0          user1      664        342110     0
0x00000000 32769      user1      664        28391740   5
0x00000000 65538      user1      664        1929302    4
```

How can I change the owner of a shared memory segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool do this. Only `ipcrm` (for deleting presented shared memory objects), `ipcmk` (for creating shared memory objects) and `ipcs` (for showing existing shared memory objects) are present (I mean [util-linux](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) project).

The kernel doesn't provide `/proc` interface for Sys V Shared Memory Objects instead of POSIX Shared Memory (`/dev/shm/<object>`).

You can write you own tool that using [shmctl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmctl.2.html) syscall. Many tutorials and books about Unix IPC have huge count of examples about `shmctl`.